# run Exec only if another Exec ran

Tags: puppet

how can I configure a Exec to run only if another Exec ran?

I have a manifest like this:

```
file { $target:
    ensure => directory
}

exec { "unzip foobar.zip -C ${target}": 
    unless => "file ${target}/some-file-form-archive"
}

exec { "chown -R $user ${target}":
    onlyif => ???
}
```

I would like the `chown` to run only if `unzip foobar.zip` ran. Of course I could start checking whether `some-file-from-archive` is already owned by `$user`, but somehow it does not seem right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an answer here already: http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/14726/run-exec-only-if-another-exec-ran/

Changing the manifest like this fixes my problem:

```
exec { 'unpack file':
  command => "unzip foobar.zip -C ${target}",
  path        => '/usr/bin',
  creates    => "${target}/some-file-form-archive",
  require    => File[$target, '<archive>'],
  notify      => Exec[fix archive],
}

exec { 'fix archive':
  command => "chown -R ${user} ${target}",
  path => '/bin',
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

**UPDATE 28.11.2014**

motivated by [Felix Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150839/run-exec-only-if-another-exec-ran/27152129#comment42812641_27152129) i tried out something else. instead of notify/refreshonly you can ensure all resource in a file-tree are owned by a user like this:

```
exec { 'fix archive':
  command => "chown -R ${user} ${target}",
  path => '/bin',
  unless => "test 0 -eq $(find ${target} \\! -user ${user} | wc -l)"
}
```

this way owner is ensured to be `$user` even if it was changed after `unpack file` ran.

Comment: Yes, although contrary to your intuition, checking the permissions via `unless` is actually cleaner.