# How to get Puppet exec to cleanup directory on failure?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to find a way to run an `exec` if another `exec` failed (so I can cleanup the directory the first exec created).

My scenario is:

1. The `exec` creates a directory but does not fully finish setting it up (fails for network error).
2. The `exec` uses `creates => $target_dir` param so subsequent runs will not try again to setup the folder.
3. The Puppet manifest is applied again after the failure and the `exec` is skipped.

I'd love to remove the directory (maybe using `file` type) if the previous `exec` was a failure. I know this is similar to http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/14726/run-exec-only-if-another-exec-ran/ and [run Exec only if another Exec ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150839/run-exec-only-if-another-exec-ran). But I only want to notify on failure (maybe exit other than 0).

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a watchdog service of some sort?

Comment: How would the watchdog service know the Puppet exec failed? I don't want to remove the dir or run the exec if the directory does exist and the first exec was completed successfully. Is "watchdog service" something new in Puppet?

Comment: Watch dog is for dynamic status updating. Puppet is used to  maintenance the client's final status. Don't mix them. Using many `exec` for this type of job is not good starting in puppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can easily do within exec is:

```
Exec { 'exec_name':
    cmd     => "${some_command} || rm -rf ${directory}",
    creates => $directory,
}
```

where ${some_command} is your actual command.

Comment: This is actually a good idea I did not think of. So simple too I'm now ashamed I didn't think of it. I'll try this out!

Comment: Attention: this makes the command "successful" on failure (regarding the exit code).

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe you can catch exit codes from `exec` calls, but what you can do is use a test to see if an expected directory or file that would be created by running the first exec successfully exists.

For example,

`exec { 'first-exec': 
  cmd     => 'foo',
  creates => '/var/www/foo/bar',
  path    => '/var/www/foo',
} -> exec { 'second-exec':
  cmd    => 'rm -rf /var/www/foo',
  unless => 'test -d /var/www/foo/bar',
}`

This runs the `first-exec`, and unless `/var/www/foo/bar` exists it runs the `second-exec`.

Comment: Careful - the `->` dependency error will actually prevent the second `exec` from running if the first one failed during the same Puppet run.

Comment: This won't work. The `/var/www/foo/bar` directory could exist in the event of a failure in which case this wouldn't work.